# Invoke Job DSL from Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-job-dsl

I need to trigger Jenkins Job DSL from pipeline (specifically, i need to mimic 'read definition file from workspace' behavior), but the job dsl plugin isn't yet on pipeline steps list. How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Job DSL wiki shows how to run Job DSL as a Pipeline step: https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/User-Power-Moves#use-job-dsl-in-pipeline-scripts

```
node {
  jobDsl scriptText: 'job("example-2")'

  jobDsl targets: ['jobs/projectA/*.groovy', 'jobs/common.groovy'].join('\n'),
       removedJobAction: 'DELETE',
       removedViewAction: 'DELETE',
       lookupStrategy: 'SEED_JOB',
       additionalClasspath: ['libA.jar', 'libB.jar'].join('\n')
}
```

Comment: `additionalClasspath` will not work if DSL script security is enabled (Manage Jenkins --> Configure Global Security --> Enable script security for Job DSL scripts )